Eliminar parte de un string dentro de una lista
Estoy empezando a estudiar Python y estoy atascada en un ejercicio.
Tengo una lista, en la que cada elemento es un string. Algunos de ellos tienen al final \n, que quisiera eliminar, ya que esos elementos serán los encabezados de mi futura tabla.
He intentado juntar todos los elementos de la lista en un único string, pero luego no tendría un criterio único para hacer un split (creo). También probé con un if '\n' in lista pero dice que no hay '\n'.
Esta es mi lista actual:
['Núm.\n', 'País\n', 'Oro', 'Plata', 'Bronce', 'Total\n']
Y esto es lo que me gustaría conseguir:
['Núm.', 'País', 'Oro', 'Plata', 'Bronce', 'Total']
Muchas gracias!

nva_lista = [x.rstrip() for x in lista]

Me ha funcionado!! Muchísimas gracias!

Puedes ignorar los \n que serían saltos de línea y obtener el carácter que buscas, agregando a tu cadena el prefijo r'\n', con r como prefijo, se omitiran las secuencias de escape, pudiendo obtener el carácter y pudiendo usar tu lógica del if, antes mencionada. Suerte

@Diego, eso no elimina los saltos de linea.

Puedes usar la función:

rstrip() : Devuelve una copia de la cadena sin los caracteres
finales. El argumento chars es una cadena que especifica el conjunto
de caracteres que se eliminarán. Si se omite o es Ninguno, el
argumento chars por defecto elimina los espacios en blanco.

ejemplo:
list = ['Núm.\n', 'País\n', 'Oro', 'Plata', 'Bronce', 'Total\n']
lista_final = [element.rstrip('\n') for element in list]
print(lista_final)

tendrías como salida:
['Núm.', 'País', 'Oro', 'Plata', 'Bronce', 'Total']


Muchas gracias! No conocía el método .rstrip.
